# what is the best way to determine a DIV's height before visible on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that will fetch data from server and compose a DIV according to it. The DIV will contain image, text and other undetermined content. I want to arrange it freely, so I need to know its height and width before it is shown to the user.

But per my understanding, I should ask browser to render it firstly, otherwise I can't know the width&height.

Is there any best way to know a DIV's width&height without showing it to user?

EDIT:

Some good guy suggests that I use jquery's .width() method, but I am wondering that if the DIV contains image, will jquery wait after the image is downloaded? I don't know the image's dimension beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `display: none` style on the div. Then use `.width()` from *jQuery* and you will get this value.

For the duration of the calculation it will use [`.swap()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L145) to set style so element is visible, call callback calculating the width and swap style back.

It will set (see the [code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L12)):

- position: absolute
- visiblity: hidden
- display: block

**EDIT** (see comments):

If you are loading a image and you want to make sure the image is loaded before you calculate the width then you can attach width calculation as the onload handler like this:

```
$('#someImg').load(function() { 
  // image is loaded, you can calculate the width
  console.log($('#test').width())); 
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/icenib/2/edit#javascript,live)** is a working example.

Comment: @BinChen: You can use `.onload` on the image and check the width there. I will update my answer soon with code example.

Comment: @BinChen I updated my answer - the link contains a working example.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is smart enough to calculate the dimensions, but only once injected into the DOM.

```
var html = "<span>My Content</span>";

//hide your element then insert it into the webpage
var html_el = $(html).hide();
$('body').append(html_el);

//get width and height
var width = html_el.width();
var height = html_el.height();

//Remove element from page if no longer needed
html_el.remove();
```

Also note, A block element `<div>` will be rendered at screen width, thus not correctly reporting the width of contained elements. To get around this you add these styles to your container: `float:left` or `display:inline-block`. Ex:

```
var html = "<div><h2>heading</h2><input type=\"text\" /></div>";

var html_el = $(html).css('float','left').hide();
```

Comment: I would try this but still need more inputs.

Comment: Thanks, as my new edit says, if the div contains image, will jquery aware of this and wait until the image is downloaded, because I don't know the image's dimension beforehand.

Comment: you need to load your images before you inject them. `$('<img src="myimg.jpg" />').load(function(){ /*done: insert html + check*/ });` http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

set `style="display:none"`
check width and then show if need

Comment: AFAIK display:none will result in the browser not rendering the element, thus not knowing its size.

Comment: When using JQuery the height and width are calculated even if display: none (as of 1.4.4 I think)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `style.display` to `'block'` and `style.visibility` to `'hidden'` the browser **should** calculate the sizes, but not show the `div`.

However, I don't know whether all browsers do this correctly.

Comment: Should be style.visibility :)

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can think of is to very quickly show it (might even be off-screen depending on your situation), then fetch its size, and then to hide it again.

But yes, if the div contains images, these need to be loaded first (or have a width / height set on them) before you know the size of the div container. You can use

```
$(document).load(function() { calculate height... })
```

to only calculate height after the complete page (including images) has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar where the height and width are both unknown. The data that populates the div with display:none is data from a snmp request so there is some time associated with getting and displaying that data. Here is a little snip of code i use to adjust the absolute position based on the height.

```
var height = $('.stripPopupContainer', this).height();

    $('.stripPopupContainer', this).css({
        left: '-5px',
        top: '-'+ height + 'px'
    });
```